# Audio player showing timestamps

Tags: windows, audio, audio-recording

I am looking for an audio player that displays the timestamps of the recording instead of the duration. For example, if I play some 5 min sound file that was recorded at 16:30:00, I want the player to show 16:30:00 at playback start, increment the time by 1s and show 16:35:00 in the end.

The player would be used to play sound from some special voice recorder, which embeds a timestamp. It must be compatible with Windows.

The mandatory file format is `.wav`, with embedded time stamps placed in them by a special voice recorder.

Free software would be nice, but commercial solutions are also welcome.

Comment: Related: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2602/1935

Comment: How does the voice recorder insert the timestamp? As part of the textual description in the tags? If so, what is the tag used for this?